# How to close uib-accordion from inside with a button click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, accordion

I would like to close accordion from inside with a button click. I am trying to set `isOpen` to false but it's not working. Is there any way to close it on button click? Thank you.

Plunker here: https://plnkr.co/edit/3xMnWRPOoEHPmguaQxd0?p=preview

```
<div uib-accordion-group is-open="isOpen" class="panel-default" heading="{{group.title}}" ng-repeat="group in groups">
  {{group.content}}
  <button ng-click="close()">close this</button>
</div>
```

```
$scope.groups = [
    {
      title: 'Dynamic Group Header - 1',
      content: 'Dynamic Group Body - 1'
    },
    {
      title: 'Dynamic Group Header - 2',
      content: 'Dynamic Group Body - 2'
    }
  ];


  $scope.isOpen = false;

  $scope.close = function(){
    $scope.isOpen = false;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could able to achieve what I needed by slightly changing @MrNobody solution. https://plnkr.co/edit/cYb5jIi3LBslUDO8xfg4?p=preview

**View:**

```
<uib-accordion close-others="true">
    <div uib-accordion-group is-open="isOpen[$index]" class="panel-default" heading="{{group.title}}" ng-repeat="group in groups">
      {{group.content}}
      <button ng-click="close($index)">close this</button>
    </div>
  </uib-accordion>
  <button ng-click="closeFromOutside()">close from outside</button>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.isOpen = [];

  $scope.groups = [
    {
      title: 'Dynamic Group Header - 1',
      content: 'Dynamic Group Body - 1'
    },
    {
      title: 'Dynamic Group Header - 2',
      content: 'Dynamic Group Body - 2'
    }
  ];

  $scope.close = function(index){
    $scope.isOpen[index] = false;

  }
  $scope.closeFromOutside = function(){
    $scope.isOpen = [];
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

I put the isOpen in the collection to have separate toggle for each accordian pill (making each pill toggle separately) and it works, check code below:

**Controller:**

```
$scope.groups = [
{
  title: 'Dynamic Group Header - 1',
  content: 'Dynamic Group Body - 1',
  isOpen: false
},
{
  title: 'Dynamic Group Header - 2',
  content: 'Dynamic Group Body - 2',
  isOpen: false
}
];

$scope.items = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3'];

$scope.addItem = function() {
  var newItemNo = $scope.items.length + 1;
  $scope.items.push('Item ' + newItemNo);
};

$scope.close = function(group){
  group.isOpen = false;
};
```

**View:**

```
<div uib-accordion-group is-open="group.isOpen" class="panel-default" heading="{{group.title}}" ng-repeat="group in groups">
  {{group.content}}
  <button ng-click="close(group)">close this</button>
</div>
```

I have modified your plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/pBT0fbNJtQhgc5kZlLbO?p=preview

Comment: Thank you. It's working fine but is there any way to achieve it without altering the object i.e. without adding isOpen key inside each object?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `ng-init` to assign new attribute `isOpen` while looping with `ng-repeat`. Updated **[Plunker code](https://plnkr.co/edit/tFgPIIdV33bT3wLrUvVh?p=preview)**.

Change template without adding attributes in controller:

```
<div uib-accordion-group ng-init="group.isOpen=false" is-open="group.isOpen" class="panel-default" heading="{{group.title}}" ng-repeat="group in groups">
  {{group.content}}
  <button ng-click="group.isOpen=false">close this</button>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

If you don't want to alter the existing object then you can have array `isOpen` which maintains  open state of accordion groups. **[Plunker code](https://plnkr.co/edit/Sgl18IjoaVAYzuwoCu8M?p=preview)**.

```
<uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime" ng-init="isOpen=[]">

    <div uib-accordion-group ng-init="isOpen[$index]=false" is-open="isOpen[$index]" class="panel-default" heading="{{group.title}}" ng-repeat="group in groups">
      {{group.content}}
      <button ng-click="isOpen[$index]=false">close this</button>
    </div>

</uib-accordion>
```

Comment: There is a form inside accordion. I would like to close the accordion when form is valid. How to set isOpen[$index] to false in controller? https://plnkr.co/edit/Bl7857NCBfJDY9pYEunm?p=preview

Comment: @SateeshKumarAlli It will be easy to help you if you can update this plunker code with forms: https://plnkr.co/edit/tFgPIIdV33bT3wLrUvVh?p=preview.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `$scope.isOpen` to `true` when you show the accordion, and then `$scope.isOpen = false` will close the accordion.

EDIT:
there is the plunker
https://plnkr.co/edit/RbbbwGaqGq8gG0JYseYw?p=preview

Comment: You just copied @arsinawaz answer.

Comment: Yep, I realised whe I pasted it. But it was not a copy ;)